# Converting .grib files to .nc files with python script?

Tags: python, netcat, grib

I am a beginner with python and looking for a python script to convert .grib files to .nc by following a path to the directory, where the file exist. I know about cdo command lines and the ncl script. However, since the number of data files are large and keep updating over time, I am looking for a way to automate the conversion process.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, share your code. If you don't have, first try, then ask.

Comment: Also, since you actually already have command line tools that do the task, it might be easier to simply write a shell script.

Comment: Thank you @jdehesa. Solved.